# Boot in emergency mode, incomplete /etc/fstab

Tags: boot, fstab

I am trying to set up a multi-boot on my machine with Ubuntu (my original OS, on `/dev/sda2`), Kali Linux and Debian. However, I got stuck halfway through my installation of Debian, and since Ubuntu took a lot of time to boot, I followed the steps of [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1112630/ubuntu-slow-to-boot-after-dual-boot/1113139#1113139) to make the boot process faster. But when I rebooted my machine, Ubuntu would only boot in emergency mode... The only thing I was able to notice was that in my `/etc/fstab` the line associated with my Ubuntu partition was gone.

I would gladly post the contents of my fstab here but I don't know how to copy it from the emergency mode to here (I am using my Kali Linux on `/dev/sda5` to write this post). Maybe there is a way to restore my fstab, to begin with?

## Edit 1

Here is the content of my `/etc/fstab`:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=95B2-5AED  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=69d6623e-0bcc-4cef-8b25-e46c98210d44 /home           ext4    defaults            0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda4 during installation
UUID=a8ee0943-0cd9-4dba-b018-ca00fc450e5d none            swap    sw              0       0
```

And here is thd result of `blkid | grep UUID`:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="95B2-5AED" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="f3ead83c-a7ca-453b-8317-a854080d37fc"
/dev/sda2: UUID="7d4d2f18-146c-4d56-b5f3-0dc605eeb9e0" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="Ubuntu" PARTUUID="94d6c9bd-30da-4abf-a784-41e20992fdd4"
/dev/sda3: UUID="69d6623e-0bcc-4cef-8b25-e46c98210d44" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="Home" PARTUUID="dd1299b6-adb1-45c0-99a6-94e922f4964b"
/dev/sda4: UUID="a8ee0943-0cd9-4dba-b018-ca00fc450e5d" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="228fa2d0-8b0c-4562-bb5a-ebb73bb00f04"
/dev/sda5: UUID="489b70a2-db82-4b0c-bebd-cf19a403ade1" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="48ba997c-e595-45c1-93c0-b97e4f7ffbf5"
/dev/sda6: UUID="9068da24-6073-45dc-a18e-29634daa3910" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="9033f352-349f-4cee-94bf-c686f462adea"
```

## Edit 2

I ran the `e2fsck` command on my Ubuntu, home and Debian partitions, and now instead of booting into emergency mode, Ubuntu starts to launch normally, but freezes after some time loading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your Kali installation is working, you can use it to access your Ubuntu installation in a chroot. To do this, run the following commands as root:

```
mkdir /ubunturoot
mount /dev/sda2 /ubunturoot
mount -o bind /dev /ubunturoot/dev
mount -o bind /dev/pts /ubunturoot/dev/pts
mount -o bind /proc /ubunturoot/proc
mount -o bind /sys /ubunturoot/sys
chroot /ubunturoot
```

Now your command prompt window (note: this particular shell only!) should be accessing your Ubuntu root filesystem just as if you had logged onto Ubuntu and become root in Ubuntu. Take a look and ensure everything is as it should be.

If your Ubuntu `/etc/fstab` is in error, now you can edit it.

Once that is fixed, first make sure the `/boot/efi` filesystem is mounted in your Ubuntu chroot:

```
mount /boot/efi
```

Then run `ls /lib/modules` to see one or more directories named with kernel version numbers. Use `update-initramfs -u -k <kernel version number>` to update the initramfs file of the respective Ubuntu kernel. (Since you are now really running Kali's kernel, you must explicitly specify the version number of Ubuntu's kernel: trying to update the default kernel would result in an error message since Ubuntu's and Kali's kernel versions are unlikely to match.)

Then check `/etc/default/grub` for boot options mentioning filesystem UUIDs or other things that may have changed on your OS installations. Fix as necessary, then run `update-grub` to update the configuration file of Ubuntu's GRUB bootloader.

Once you've fixed all the problems you've found, undo the temporary chroot environment manually:

```
umount /boot/efi
exit # out of the chroot environment, back to Kali native view of the filesystem
umount /ubunturoot/sys
umount /ubunturoot/proc
umount /ubunturoot/dev/pts
umount /ubunturoot/dev
umount /ubunturoot
rmdir /ubunturoot
```

Comment: Thanks, but: 1) I don't know how to fix my `fstab`, that's what I'm asking; 2) `ls /lib/modules` shows two kernel numbers, how do I know which one is Ubuntu's? 3) There is no UUID mentioned in `/etc/default/grub`...

Comment: 1) now you should be able to at least show us your current Ubuntu `fstab`, which would make it a lot easier for us to help you, 2) if you followed the chroot instructions, they are both Ubuntu's: the latest kernel update and the previous one for backup, 3) good, that's one potential source of problems eliminated then.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot; I have been able to fix my `fstab` now thanks to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/516442/destroyed-fstab-file-by-mistake-need-to-restore-it), and now I can boot on Ubuntu. The only problem left is that my machine seems to be trying to load something (a partition?) at boot and takes a lot of time before starting to launch Ubuntu...

Comment: Your `/etc/fstab` now seems to have all the correct UUIDs. Note that Ubuntu's boot splash screen allows you to press Esc to see what is going on during the boot process. But you said "takes a lot of time *before starting to launch Ubuntu*": is it before or after the first display of GRUB appears? If it's before, run `efibootmgr -v` and add the output to your question, please: you might have a stale UEFI boot entry or two in there. They should be easy to remove using the `efibootmgr` command with the appropriate options, but I'd like to take a look first, to perhaps give you the exact commands.

Comment: And if the slowdown/hang happens *after* GRUB, you can press Esc in the Ubuntu boot splash screen to see a diagnostic display. That might help in getting more information about what exactly is causing the start-up hang/slowdown.

Answer (score 0):

My evil addition to fstab caused read only also [everywhere]... Found this solution;
Boot from a (previous version doesn't matter) server install CD or stick, select "Rescue a broken system" (,language,keyboard) and insert the known servername & select "Device to use as root filesystem" [;/dev/sda1]. Select "Execute a shell in /dev/sda1" and *in the bottom of your screen* you find the # .... with #cd /etc I was permitted to edit fstab (hashing out 'the evil').... exit and reboot.